# Node - sqlite3 module installation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, sqlite

When I tried to install sqlite3 using `sudo npm install sqlite3`, but it is showing some warnings and error messages [image][image]

Can anyone suggest a solution. Thanks

Comment: wow! such colors, much small!

Comment: Sorry I didn't get u. Can you make it more clear?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be a joke. What I mean is that it is really cumbersome to read from screenshots. It would be better if you could list the errors.

Answer (score 2):

sqlite require compile/build system. It's means that you must configure [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)

Also you can use node-pre-gyp. It provides already compiled modules

```
npm i node-pre-gyp
npm i sqlite
```

Recently sqlite was available in pre-gyp only for Node 5.x (or older).